# .net core .editorconfig warnings not showing in Visual Studio Error List

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, editorconfig

In our .net core project I just added a .editorconfig file (from the dafault .NET template available when using Add New Item to the solution) and changed all the severity levels to "warning" (to see if we needed to agree on stuff). But when I build, there are no warnings or errors displayed, except for the file I currently have open. The documentation leads me to believe I should see compiler notes from all files built, if I have the severity level set to warning or error. How can I see all the warnings in the solution?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/editorconfig-language-conventions?view=vs-2019#severity-levels

If I build using the command line `dotnet build` I see no warnings at all.

Answer (score -1):

I think the last paragraph of ["code consistency"](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2019#code-consistency) explains that.

> (...) As long as you open the code file in an EditorConfig-compliant editor, the text editor settings are implemented. (...)

Comment: OP has already tagged this as a Visual Studio issue, and I'm pretty sure VS is .editorconfig-compliant...